# Are you able to farm fragments in Bastion?

Tags: bastion

I've come upon my first forge, allowing me to upgrade my weapons. However, I'm leery on spending fragments to upgrade my current weapons if I wind up switching them out for different weapons later on.

Are there a limited number of fragments in Bastion, or are there locations where I can farm them?

If there are a limited number of fragments, do I need to concern myself with conserving them, or will the game provide me with enough that won't be a problem?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As [Mana mentioned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28417/are-you-able-to-farm-fragments-in-bastion/28423#28423), you'll get access to the Smoking Pipe at some point, which allows you to combat waves of enemies in return for fragments. You'll also eventually gain access to the Bedroll and Stockpot, which function in the same way, but offer variation on the narration and enemy types.

[image: dungeon items]

More specifically, the Smoking Pipe pits you against enemies from the Old World, the Bedroll pits you against Ura warriors, and the Stockpot pits you against beasts from the Wild. They all offer about the same reward as far as fragments are concerned, and without any bonuses to fragment collection you can expect to get approximately 750 fragments per run.

To increase this amount, consider enabling one or more idols in the Shrine, if you have one. Not only does this give a percentage bonus for fragments collected, completing these dungeons with at least one idol enabled completes a vigil at the Memorial, which will grant you an additional one-time lump bonus.

Comment: I'd avoid the smoking pipe when choosing a level however.  It's difficult to fight effectively when a lot of holes gets punched into the ground, especially since it happens relatively early in the challenge.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can farm fragments in Bastion. Later on in the game, you get access to the Smoking Pipe.

[image: stoner joke goes here]

Using the Pipe will take you into a special dungeon where you defeat waves of enemies and are awarded with large amounts of fragments for your troubles.

Comment: Nice timing, I just found this myself!