# Which kinds of objects are worth destroying for fragments?

Tags: bastion

When just raging for a while and destroying objects, it's pretty clear that different kinds of destructible objects provide different number of blue fragments. Pieces of walls and masonry, for instance, seem to provide none, while potted plants always net a few fragments.

I don't think I want to invest the time in destroying every single object in the hope in will get me shards, but I don't want to miss out on "valuable" objects, either. Is there some sort of guideline or chart which would indicate which objects I would want to destroy and which ones I can skip?

I realize the types of objects change between levels, but even a rough guideline will do.

Comment: I was also wondering that, but then I wondered if shards are really in such dire demand so as to warrant running around smashing things instead of progressing through the game more "naturally".

Comment: I believe you mean "fragments", as "shards" have a specific and different meaning in the context of this game. And I personally found destroying effectively everything quite easy... but then I do like to carry at least one wide or area attack weapon. :)

Comment: In my experience, the quantity of fragments that you get from playing the levels is dwarfed by the fragments that you get from vigils. Unless you're really going for some "absolute 100% completion" play-through, I wouldn't worry about picking up every fragment.

Comment: @Slubb you may have a point, but the little munchkin inside me cries every time I pass on an opportunity for loot :(

Comment: @Oak you can farm them anyway (see [Are you able to farm fragments in Bastion?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28417/are-you-able-to-farm-fragments-in-bastion)), so you can always get more if you need them.

Comment: @Oak i have suffered from this same munchkin since Diablo 2 ;)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After almost two playthroughs, here are my observations:

**Objects that give notable fragments are objects that are man-made and could be considered to 'hold' something.** This includes:

- crates
- barrels
- wagons
- shop booths

**Objects that don't give fragments are usually natural or man-made but used as fencing.**

**Occasionally, I see something break this rule, but rarely does it give a significant amount of fragments.** For example, I think there are some bones that give fragments. However, they don't give many. I've started ignoring anything that doesn't match my first rule in my "time vs. reward" calculation.

As a side note, the most abundant sources of fragments are not objects at all. Instead, they are:

- Vigils
- Who Knows Where
- The Shield challenge
- Monsters (especially with Idols active)

I've also noticed that I've been getting 2.5k shards after every level in New Game Plus where I place a shard in the monument. That was also when I activated 8/10 idols. I haven't tried disabling the idols to see if there is a correlation. At the time, I was level 7 or 8 and didn't have my weapons fully upgraded.

Comment: I did notice that *bones*, however, do provide a lot of fragments when destroyed.

Comment: @Oak: Interesting. I've seen them give maybe 1 or 2. I usually only bother with bones if they are close to something larger, and then only to roll through the bones to get to the larger object quicker.

Comment: I started getting the 2.5K shards on New Game+, with only 0-1 idol activated, so I think it's a bonus to substitude for the upgrade you already have.